# How to export a table from Microsoft SQL Server to Excel?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, export-to-csv

I have set up an automatic job to run a query/report on Microsoft SQL Server. The job runs fine and produces the correct data. However, I am having trouble with what syntax to use in order to get the automatic query to transfer all of the report into an Excel spreadsheet and save it into my documents (if this is even possible..).

This has to be automatic and part of the Job as the query/report runs overnight.

Thanks!

Comment: Huh? Is this running on your local machine or the server? If it is the server who's documents should it be? We need quite a bit more detail about your task to be able to help.

Comment: "The job runs fine and produces the correct data". Where do you see the data right now? How are you exporting it currently? You don't have anywhere near enough info in your question

Comment: It is running on a server currently, I just want the report to export to the servers drive.  In essence, I need my report/query to export as a csv file and save itself onto the servers drive.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Open a New Excel

2 - Go to Data Tab

3 - Select From Other Sources (Refer image attached)

4 - Select From SQL Server (Refer image attached)

[image]

5 - Enter the Server authentication and connection details to proceed further

This would ask for your server details and authentication. Then it would be asking the range or a cell were the data to be linked or exported.

Comment: Follow this link http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/feature/The-SQL-Server-Import-and-Export-Wizard-how-to-guide